# Exclude missing values from model performance calculation

Tags: r, missing-data, r-caret, imputation

I have a dataset and I want to build a model, preferably with the `caret` package. My data is actually a time series but the question is not specific to time series, it's just that I work with `CreateTimeSlices` for the data partition.

My data has a certain amount of missing values `NA`, and I imputed them separately of the `caret` code. I also kept a record of their locations:

```
# a logical vector same size as the data, which obs were imputed NA
imputed=c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
imputed[imputed] <- NA; print(imputed)
#### [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA FALSE FALSE
```

I know there is an option in Caret `train` function to either exclude the `NA` or impute them with different techniques. That's *not* what I want. I need to build the model on the already imputed dataset but **I want to exclude the imputed points from the calculation of the error** indicators (RMSE, MAE, ...).

I don't know how to do this in caret. In my first script I tried to do the whole cross validation manually, and then I had a customized error measure:

```
actual = c(5, 4, 3, 6, 7, 5)
predicted = c(4, 4, 3.5, 7, 6.8, 4)
Metrics::rmse(actual, predicted) # with all the points
#### [1] 0.7404953
sqrt(mean( (!imputed)*(actual-predicted)^2 , na.rm=T)) # excluding the imputed
#### [1] 0.676757
```

How can I handle this way of doing in `caret`? Or is there another way to avoid coding everything by hand?

Comment: Sounds like something requiring custom code, not `caret`, to me.

Comment: I also thought of using the `weights` argument but it's not clear when it is taken into account or not.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you are looking for this but here is a simple solution by creating a function:

```
i=which(imputed==F) ## As you have index for NA values

metric_na=function(fun, actual, predicted, index){
    fun(actual[index], predicted[index])
}

metric_na(Metrics::rmse, actual, predicted, index = i)
0.676757
metric_na(Metrics::mae, actual, predicted, index = i)
0.54
```

Also you can just use the index directly while calculating the desired metrics:

```
Metrics::rmse(actual[i], predicted[i])
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice function that really helps, I will surely implement it it noone thinks its possible with caret :-)

Comment: I think it would be possible but it would require some effort. Also look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28232658/how-to-change-metrics-using-the-librarycaret/28278334#28278334) post if you haven't.